# Which kind of relics can be found?

Tags: clicker-heroes

I'm currently playing Clicker Heroes with the new update which introduces relics. I just wanted two things to know.

1. Which kind of relics can be found? I've found some different kind of items so far. Common, Uncommon, Rare, Fabled and Epic. Will be there more kind of items to be found? What is better? An Fabled or an Epic?
2. Additionally I want to know whats about the level? There are some level mentioned in the item description. I get some items with higher and sometimes items with lower levels than before. Is this purely random? I mentioned that the items with higher level provide (as expected) better abilities than items with lower items even if they have a higher rarity. But I cannot determine if it's purely random or if it is depending on the time/level where the relic is dropped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [wiki page for relics](http://clickerheroes.wikia.com/wiki/Relics) and [reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/ClickerHeroes/comments/3alqox/an_informative_analysis_of_relics/) will be your best bet for up to date information (and is still being fleshed out); but let me at least try and summarize your questions:

1.)  There's 8 rarity levels (going from most common to least common):

```
 - Common
 - Uncommon
 - Rare
 - Epic
 - Fabled
 - Mythical
 - Legendary
 - Transcendent
```

2.)  The level appears to be dependent on what zone the Relic Ooze spawns.  From the aforementioned wiki:

> Relic levels are calculated depending on the zone level in which the
>   Relic Ooze spawns. The higher the zone level, the higher the Relic
>   level will be. A Relic obtained at zone 1500 will always have a higher
>   level than a Relic at zone 1400.

and from the reddit discussion; the formula is apparently:

> Relic Level = MAX(ceiling(50 * (1 -1.2 -spawn_zone/100+1 )),1)

Comment: Thanks @Jim-B! This answers my question! Really appreciate your help.